# What screwdriver should I use to remove drawer handles?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

I'm changing the handles on my drawers, and I can't get the screws out. I think the screws might be a Phillips raised countersunk but I'm not sure. All I know is that it is a Phillips head screw. What screwdriver should i use, and what size?

Comment: Use a medium sized phillips head screw driver. If it doesn't fit, get a smaller or bigger one.

Comment: A size 2 is the most common size but the cabinet hardware usually uses a size 1.

Answer (score 2):

The head shape of the screw rarely has any impact on the type of driver needed. You probably want a standard #2 Phillips.

Very few screws are #1 outside of very small electronics applications. Even tiny screws are often #2. Always try the larger size first.  If I had a nickel for every #2 screw I've seen mangled by a #1 driver....

Most reversible (hardware store impulse buy) screwdrivers provide a #1 and a #2. Even if they look rather fat, the very tip is what matters. There are many configurations of a #2, but the tips are all the same.

The larger size with the obviously flat end is a #3, and they're more common in such applications as TV wall mounts.

Answer (score 2):

Ikea uses Pozidriv screws for everything. It looks like a Philips head but it's what they use in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flat screwdriver if the screw has 'flats' on it. You can get more torque and it will [cam out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cam_out) less. (don't stab yourself)

Pushing hard enough, so that whatever screwdriver you use doesn't cam out, is half the battle.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a Phillips head but it is not, actually it is a slotted screw with cross slots with no hole for the pointed driver tip, so use slotted driver.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How do you know this? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.